# Create ProgressBar with Text label near ProgressBar current value

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

Maybe the headline a little unclear so please see this image:

[image]

OR:

[image]

How can i create this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a ValueChanged event of the progress bar & set the value to the popup. Refer sample below:

```
//Define a popup in your code, add a Label to it; the below code could be added to the 
//ctor/any other block which would be invoked prior to the ValueChanged event. 
//Please ensure Popup is declared such that it is visble/accessible in any of the 
//functions - in this case, the ValueChanged Event & where you decide to add label & 
//placement values to it.

Popup pop = new Popup();
Label lbl = new Label();
pop.Child = lbl;
pop.Placement = placementMode.Relative;
pop.PlacementTarget = progressBar;//assuming name of ProgressBar is progressbar

private void ProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    pop.IsOpen = true;
    //Set the horizontal offset of Popup in accordance to dimensions of your progress bar
    (pop.Child as Label).Content = progressBar.Value.ToString();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    pop.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Note: If you need the popup look & feel as per your screenshots you would have to modify template of the label.

Comment: I am changing my progress bar via timer and i cannot see the popup

Comment: Would you want the popup to stay open once the timer starts? If yes, comment out pop.IsOpen = false.